The reason for strings instead of symbols
I was wondering about passing a string to check the existence of a symbol, so I created the following function,
but all the answers were :INTERNAL, so it was useless.
I understand the reason, but does anyone know why lisp works this way?
(defun find-foo (s)
  (find-symbol (symbol-name s)))

(defun find-bar (s)
  (find-symbol (string s)))

* (find-foo 'never-used-symbol)
NEVER-USED-SYMBOL
:INTERNAL
* (find-bar 'still-unused-symbol)
STILL-UNUSED-SYMBOL
:INTERNAL


The two symbols start to exist at the moment you create them as a parameter to the call. What is the expected behaviour? If you do not want symbol to be created before call to the functions, pass a string (upcased) to the second one, or use (just to be fancy) symbol not in the package you are in, such as #:NEVER-USED-SYMBOL or :NEVER-USED-SYMBOL

If the READ-eval-print-loop READS a symbol, then it exists. Why should it not? :INTERNAL means, that this symbol is internal in the current package, where it was READ.

I understand the reason, but does anyone know why lisp works this way? this is unclear, can you be more precise in your question? explain for example what is your understanding and how else could Lisp work?

The Lisp REPL works by first reading a form from a stream of characters, and then evaluating it.
So the Lisp reader's job is to turn (the start of) a stream of characters into an object represented by that stream of characters.  In particular the reader turns a stream of characters starting with ' (in other words the character #\' into a two-element list (quote <x>), where <x> is the object returned by reading the rest of the stream.  In turn, it reads never-used-symbol and returns a symbol whose name is "NEVER-USED-SYMBOL" and which is interned in the package current at read-time.  If such a symbol already exists it returns that, otherwise it creates a new symbol and interns it in the current package, returning that.
So a stream whose characters are "'never-used-symbol" is read as the list (quote never-used-symbol).
In other words the reader creates symbols and other Lisp objects, which is its job.
The evaluator then evaluates this form to return the symbol itself: the value of (quote <x>) is <x>.
find-symbol's first argument is a string designator: a symbol is a string designator which designates the string which is its name.  So in this case you gave it a symbol and it dutifully looked for, and found the symbol whose name it was which is ... the same symbol.

Symbols, which are by the Lisp reader not interned, are written as #:symbolname.
Example:
CL-USER 3 > (find-foo '#:non-interned-symbol)
NIL
NIL

CL-USER 4 > (find-bar '#:non-interned-symbol)
NIL
NIL

By default Lisp symbols are interned in the current package, since that allows us to use symbols with the same name (and package) as the exact same objects.
